# how to safely update way generators 3.0 package in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, package, composer-php, way-generators

i figured out too late that way generators version 3 package is not compatible with laravel version 4.2 it only work with laravel 5, now i need to switch to a previous version of the package and i do not know how to do it properly as my laravel project is in the half way.

Thank you so much for any further help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your composer.json file to use `"way/generators": "~2.0"`. Once that is done, run the following command:

```
composer update "way/generators" --dev
```

By providing the package name to the composer command, composer will only update the specified package.

Comment: whats the difference between "~2.0 " and " 2.* "  ?

Comment: @Mounir Documentation for composer package versioning is [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions). Those two values would mean the same thing: ">= 2.0 and < 3.0".